# How can I use OMEMO in Gajim on 16.10?

Tags: encryption, 16.10, xmpp, omemo

I want to use OMEMO for encrypted group chat. Apparently Gajim is currently (February 2017) the best client for this. How do I enable OMEMO in Gajim on Ubuntu 16.10?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Gajim from "Software" as usual (package name `gajim` version `0.16.5-1`)
2. Start Gajim and navigate to Edit | Plugins
3. The first time you start plugins, the "Plugin Installer" plugin will want to update itself. Do this, then close the plugins.
4. Open Edit | Plugins again.
5. Go the the "Available" tab and wait for it to load
6. Find "OMEMO" on the list and install it.
7. Close Gajim.
8. Visit https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/python-axolotl/download
9. Download the latest version (`python-axolotl_0.1.35-3_all.deb` at time of writing) from your closest mirror
10. Install the .deb file
11. Start Gajim and enable the OMEMO plugin (you may need to restart Gajim again)
12. You can now use OMEMO with contacts that also have OMEMO-enabled clients.

**Notes:**

- This will probably be simpler in Ubuntu 17.04 onwards. Just install the packages `gajim` and `gajim-omemo`

**References:**

- https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim-plugins/wikis/OmemoGajimPlugin